# how to load pdf file in UIWebview center

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I am new in ios developement.I am trying to display a pdf in a UIWebview center.i have a pdf in mainbundle.Here is what my PDF looks like now when loaded in a UIWebView: (I put in a brown gradient as the UIWebView's background so you can see what I mean better).
[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UIWebView *theWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];
[theWebView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[theWebView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[theWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
[theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:filePathURL]];

[self.view addSubview:theWebView];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I would like to centre that so that the bottom margin is the same as the top margin. How would I do this with a PDF (local)?

Comment: UIWebView is not meant to be used like that.

Look for pdf viewers / parsers, something like this https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Comment: @NimrodGutman is it possible to load pdf file uiwebview center with the help of html code using

Comment: have already seen the screenshot somewhere...you already have asked any question on the same?

Comment: @iOSCoder yes but not same.previously asked how to load pdf file uiwebview full screen

Comment: @Ravindhiran...how about having (1)one view1 with gray back ground (2)then adding webview at the center of view1 ?

Comment: @iOSCoder i have updated my question please check it now..

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = rect.size;
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is the ideal solution for your question.

First Get the width and height of PDF==>

```
float width = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(PageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox).size.width;

float height = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(PageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox).size.height;
```

where Pageref is the PDF page reference.

```
CGSize pdfSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

//Create one superView to webview

UIView *supView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];
supView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.663 green:0.855 blue:0.341 alpha:1]
```

//Then webview

```
UIWebView *theWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, pdfSize.width, pdfSize.height)]];
    [theWebView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [theWebView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [theWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    [theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:filePathURL]];
    [supView addSubview: theWebView];

    [self.view addSubview: supView];
```

**EDIT:**

Get Pageref(part),

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

CFURLRef pdfURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
//file ref
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDocRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef) pdfURL);

CGPDFPageRef PageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDocRef, 1);

float width = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page1, kCGPDFMediaBox).size.width;

float height = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page1, kCGPDFMediaBox).size.height;

NSLog(@"%f %f",height,width);
```

Comment: i don't want to change UIWebview frame dynamically.it is fixed frame  why because if the user want to zoom the pdf file it is to be expand full screen.